# I had installed program, but when I want to upgrade, it could not find him

Tags: apt, package-management, kali-linux, upgrade

I had installed youtube-dl :

```
# youtube-dl
Usage: youtube-dl [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]

youtube-dl: error: You must provide at least one URL.
Type youtube-dl --help to see a list of all options.
```

But when I run it with --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 [URL], it ended with

```
WARNING: 0g7KawdsVSQ: writing DASH m4a. Only some players support this container. Install ffmpeg or avconv to fix this automatically.
ERROR: ffprobe or avprobe not found. Please install one.
```

And when I want to upgrade youtube-dl package, to install additional files:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... E: Unable to locate package youtube-dl
```

And when I want to install ffmpeg:

```
# apt-get install ffmpeg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ffmpeg is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

A few details:

- Using Kali GNU/Linux 2.0 (sana) 64-bit.
- I'm trying to upgrade, with command: `apt-get upgrade youtube-dl`

> ```
> >   
> > 
> >  # apt-cache policy youtube-dl ffmpeg
> > 
> >     
> > 
> > > ffmpeg:
> > >       Installed: (none)
> > >       Candidate: (none)
> > >       Version table:
> > >     N: Unable to locate package youtube-dl
> ```

```
# apt-cache policy
```

> ```
> Package files:
>  100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
>      release a=now
>  500 http://security.kali.org/kali-security/ sana/updates/non-free amd64 Packages
>      release o=Kali,a=kali-current,n=sana,c=non-free
>      origin security.kali.org
>  500 http://security.kali.org/kali-security/ sana/updates/contrib amd64 Packages
>      release o=Kali,a=kali-current,n=sana,c=contrib
>      origin security.kali.org
>  500 http://security.kali.org/kali-security/ sana/updates/main amd64 Packages
>      release o=Kali,a=kali-current,n=sana,c=main
>      origin security.kali.org
> Pinned packages:
> ```

EDID 2:
  Sources.list

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2.0 _Sana_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20150811-08:02]/ sana contrib main non-free

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2.0 _Sana_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20150811-08:02]/ sana contrib main non-free

deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security/ sana/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security/ sana/updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment: "And when i wanna upgrade youtube-dl package". Please include what command line you used. In the question,  not in a comment. Also state with distribution are you using, and version. Also post the result of `apt-cache policy youtube-dl ffmpeg`. Also `apt-cache policy`. Again, in the question, not in comments.

Comment: I edited post...

Comment: There was second answer, i apologize for not review ans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing sources in your `sources.list`.

See [Kali sources.list Repositories](http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories), which says:

> On a standard, clean install of Kali Linux, you should have the
>   following two entries present in /etc/apt/sources.list:
>
> ```
> deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
> deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
> ```

You appear to have the second line, but not the first. Check your `sources.list`.

Comment: i edited my question, with content about sources.list, take a look if u can

Comment: Yes, add the first line as shown above. Then run `apt-get update`.